# Modules resources root in IDEA : scala multi module projet

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm working with a multi module IDEA project in scala.

The project contains 16 modules.

All of those modules are based on the same common sbt config :

```
  resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "resources",
  resourceDirectory in Test := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "test" / "resources",
  resourceDirectory in IntegrationTest := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "it" / "resources",
```

My problem is that when syncing the project with IDEA, 2 of the 16 modules will consistently fail to mark their src/main/resources folder as `resources root`, but will instead have it flagged as `test resources root`

I can change it manually, but every single reimport of the project will re-flag them again.

After a bit of digging in sbt, I found that from sbt of point of view :

- For all 16 modules, src/main/resources is the resource directory for Compile
- For all 16 modules, both src/main/resources and src/test/resources are resources directories for test, which I find a bit odd, but I'm not sure.

Thanks !

Minimal build.sbt that will exhibit the problem :

```
import sbt.Keys.resourceDirectory


lazy val coreSettings = Seq(
  organization := "C4stor",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.6",
  resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "resources",
  resourceDirectory in Test := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "test" / "resources",
  resourceDirectory in IntegrationTest := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "it" / "resources"
)

lazy val `module_one` = project
  .in(file("module_one"))
  .settings(
    coreSettings
  )
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
```

If you create the actual src/main/resources and src/test/resources folders in module_one directory, IDEA will incorrectly flag src/main/resources

Comment: The same way your test code has access to your main code, your test code can also access your main resources.

Comment: What is your sbt version? Can you add your entire `build.sbt` and specify which projects keep failing? I'd guess that you configure something differently for those 2 projects.

Comment: sbt version is 1.3.7 
I'm gonna try and produce a minimal reproducible example since the actual file would be quite sensitive

Comment: Well, I found a way to fix while doing the minimal example... Not sure what's happening inside though, but seems good enough

Comment: I don't think you need any of the resource directory parameters in your coreSettings.  By default, the sub-modules will assume you have a main, and test subdirectory.  add .configs(IntegrationTest).settings(Defaults.itSettings) and you will have your desired third src location of `src/it` as well https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#Integration+Tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every module that has  `.configs(IntegrationTest)` also needs to have Defaults.itSettings in its settings in order for idea to correctly map resources folders.

In the example given, it becomes

```
lazy val `module_one` = project
  .in(file("module_one"))
  .settings(
    coreSettings, Defaults.itSettings
  )
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
```